# Downgrade package from backports back to stable

Tags: apt

I updated `tmux` on my VPS with:

```
apt-get install -t squeeze-backports tmux -V
```

And needed to get back to previous version to recover some running sessions, so I went to look which version of `tmux` is the right for Debian and then downgraded with:

```
apt-get install tmux=1.3-2+squeeze1
```

But it took me a lot of time to figure out this specific command and look for a proper version. Is there a shortcut that automatically gets the stable version? I tried different combinations for `-t` flag, but it didn't help.

`apt-cache policy tmux`:

```
tmux:
  Installed: 1.6-2~bpo60+1
  Candidate: 1.6-2~bpo60+1
  Version table:
 *** 1.6-2~bpo60+1 0
        200 http://www.backports.org/debian/ squeeze-backports/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.3-2+squeeze1 0
        500 http://debian.newdream.net/ squeeze/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: `apt-get install tmux/stable` would also work. This would force a downgrade if necessary.

Comment: Doesn't work. `E: Release 'stable' for 'tmux' was not found`

Comment: My bad. Try `oldstable` or `squeeze` instead.

Comment: Thanks. That works. Will `oldstable` gone when a new `oldstable is released?

Comment: Oldstable is `stable - 1`. When a new stable is released, you might still be able to get at the squeeze sources, but you won't be able to use the `oldstable` name. `squeeze` should still work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easier way is using the release option on apt, example:

```
sudo apt-get install tmux/stable
```

or, in case you are using the name of the release instead of the tier (ie. squeeze, jeesie, sid instead of stable, testing, unstable) you should use that name instead:

```
sudo apt-get install tmux/squeeze
```

This will install the latest version available in the specified suite (stable, testing, unstable, stable-backports, sid, etc.)

Comment: Neither `-t stable` nor `tmux/stable` worked.

Comment: @FaheemMitha mm... the manual says -t should be the equivalent to pinning the package... mmm....

Comment: @techtonik you should use `squeeze` instead of `stable`.

Answer (score 0):

let's say you want to downgrade a package like geary

```
sudo apt -t buster-backports purge geary
```

or just

```
sudo apt purge geary
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install geary
```

or

```
sudo apt install geary/stable
```

Comment: Purging shouldn’t be necessary to downgrade; it will have the unfortunate effect of deleting any local configuration changes.